# tcl code to catch repeated lines in file

Tags: process, duplicates, tcl, lines, tclsh

Hi I have the following scenario. I read in a file line by line; then each like will look like: 2 0, 3 0, 4 0, 9 0, 11 3 etc; like "string  string". each like then will be put is a variable; $line will have one set of value in each iteration within while loop; now I want to be able to catch if a line is repeated or similar to one we saw previously..

myFile will contain:

```
2 0 
3 0
9 0 
11 3  
 3 5
2 9 
2 0 
3 5
```

Here is the code:

```
set in [open myFile r]
set exline ""
while {[gets $in line] >= 0} {
    lappend exline $line
    if { [lsearch $exline $line] > 0} {
        puts "same number repeated $line"
    }
}
close $in
```

Comment: Your problem isn't entirely clear, but my guess is that your program will work better if you move the lappend invocation to just below the if invocation, i e to a new line between the right brace of if and the right brace of while.

Comment: Thanks but that will not work. I expect the result to be:

Comment: <pre>
same number repeated 2 0 
same number repeated 2 0
same number repeated 3 5
same number repeated 3 5
</pre>

Comment: And you're not getting that, partly because you're putting the lappend in wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
set fid [open myFile]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {dict incr lines [string trim $line]}
close $fid
dict for {line count} $lines {if {$count > 1} {puts "duplicated: $line"}}
```

```
duplicated: 2 0
duplicated: 3 5
```

Comment: Hi @glen-jackman.. How would you deal with two files then,.
one file has some contents for example:
1st File format :
stripe   1 item pos 2  deck 4 1 
stripe   2 item pos 22  deck 7 2
stripe   3 item pos 3  deck 4 3
stripe   4 item pos 5  deck 8 4 
stripe   5 item pos 2  deck 4 5 

combination of item pos # AND deck # number must be unique.. so stripe 1 and stripe 5 have similar pos# and deck #..  How can you catch these: 1; within file? or combination of two files! 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about `set fid [open "| cat file1 file2"]` -- will first concatenate the files (using the system's `cat` executable). Or else: `foreach filename {file1 file2} {set fid [open $filename]; while ...; close $fid}`

Comment: yes!, that works.. how ever it is not out putting the whole line: 
 the string matched which is:    

while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
set b  "[lindex $line 4] [lindex $line 6]\n": 
dict incr lines [string trim $b]}
dict for {line count} $lines {if {$count > 1} {puts "duplicated: $line"}}
duplicated: 2 5 
I want to see the whole line rather then the only matched snippet of the line..

Comment: Then you need to store the whole line in a separate dict, indexed by $b: `while {...} {set b [string trim "[lindex $line 4] [lindex $line 6]"]; dict incr count $b; dict set original $b $line}; dict for {idx num} $count {if {$num > 1} {puts "duplicated: [dict get $original $idx]"}}`

Comment: Note, that only outputs the *last* matching line: if there are 3 or more matches, you'll only see the last one